# Publishing in Visual Studio 2015 - Could not find part of path

Tags: visual-studio

Am trying to publish my Web Application. It worked fine literally 15 minutes ago and not aware of anything changing in the meantime. Now receiving this error:

Copying file bin\myApp.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\myApp.dll failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\myApp.dll'.

Tried copying the dll manually and Windows just hangs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I've fixed it. Had to remote directly into the server and cut the release folder to the desktop then copy it back again. Window's threw some permission errors, which it shouldn't have as I have full permissions but worked when I clicked "Try Again". Then manually inserted the dll the same way and tried publishing again. This time it worked. Bit of a weird one but seems to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when you have a files that the path that is longer than 255 chars.

Ensuring all file paths from the drive root to all the files in the Debug\Package\PackageTmp folder were shorter than 255 corrected the issue for me

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, path is longer than 255 chars, but I'm not sure how to correct. As far as I can tell, the path is being generated by msbuild and the packages I want to include are adding to the length. The exact path: C:\Users\Bryce\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\employeeconnect--1938606380\obj\Debug\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.7.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.targets
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens to me when a file is locked (still in use) by windows.

Try right clicking on the solution and doing "clean" solution. Then rebuilding.

If that does not work. Try cleaning solution, closing Visual Studio, re-opening it, then publishing it.

Comment: Nice idea but sadly no change

Comment: Try deleting the release folder completely and publishing

Comment: No it really didn't like that

Comment: Could not write lines to file "obj\Release\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs". Could not find a part of the path '\\scooby\Debug site\myApp\myApp\obj\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs'.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this problem and I've found out, in my case, that the folder was not being created when the project was published in IIS. So I've copied the folder from my project's directory to the location where the project is published.

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that the cause was the permission set in the Build folder located in the project folder where the software is compiled to.

For some reason the permission were not set to full, and on further investigation the delete permissions were not set to active.

This meant that the first compile succeeded, but the second failed because the original folder could not be cleared by Visual Studio, or the original files could not be overwritten.

Setting the permissions to full fixed this issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30977334)